# Python - array of dictionaries to excel spreadsheet or csv

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv

I have multiple of arrays like this

```
 - [{'ID': 001},{'Document': 'Documentation_Name_1'}]
 - [{'ID': 002},{'Document': 'Documentation_Name_2'}]
```

and I wanted to export it to excel or CSV file 
with two (ID and Document) columns with multiple rows

Any advice or help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using tablib and csv writer libraries but I am stuck where I can't insert multiple row accordingly to the key from dictionary

Comment: @CalvinTey if you include the code you have tried so far, people can more easily suggest what you can do to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using pandas, you could:

concatenate your dicts to have:

```
{'ID': '001', 'Document': 'Documentation_Name_1'}
```

Then make a list of your dicts:

```
[{'ID': 001,'Document': 'Documentation_Name_1'}, {'ID': 002, 'Document': 'Documentation_Name_2'}]
```

Export your list of dicts to a pandas dataframe:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame(YOUR_LIST_OF_DICTS, columns=["ID", "Document"])
```

And then export the dataframe to a csv file:

```
final_df.to_csv("filename.csv")
```